# Drools how to update object while avoiding infinite loop

Tags: drools

Here is my logic:

Given a project and a list of recommendations.
Rule1:
For each recommendation, if it will incur any cost, add the recommendation into the project costList.

Rule2:
If the project costList is not empty, do X

```
rule "Rule 1" salience -1
when
    $rec: Recommendation()
    $project: Project($costList: costList)
then
     if (recommendation incur cost){
      $projectResult.getCostList().add($rec);
      update($project) // update needed to notify Rule2 costList is no longer empty
    } 
end

rule "Rule 2" salience -2
when
   $project: Project($costList: costList.empty == false )
then 
   // do X
end
```

### Here is the problem

#### if I call update, rule 1 will fire itself again into infinite loop. But if I do not call update, rule 2 condition will always be false because actionList is empty when I insert the project into the drool working memory. What is the correct way to avoid the infinite loop while updating the object?

PS. What is the different between `update()` and `notify()` beside notify is a syntax sugar

The logic to feed rule engine working memory look something like:

```java
KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
Project project = new Project();
project.costList = new ArrayList();
List<Recommendation> rList;
for (recommendation: rList){
  kieSession.insert(recommendation);
}
kieSession.insert(project);
kieSession.fireAllRules();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is that the call of update() on the whole fact notify a global change to the engine of your instance of type `Project`, and in turn the rule with higher priority/salience is designed to just match on a `Project()` without any constraint.

In other words, the engine is behaving as intended, but you have not achieved what you wanted to actually do.

You have several strategies you can employ here, overall you might consider refactoring rule 1 something ~like:

```
rule "Rule 1" salience -1
when
    $rec: Recommendation()
    $project: Project($costList: costList not contains $rec)
then
     if (recommendation incur cost){
       modify( $project ) {
         getCostList().add($rec);
       }
     }
end
```

should already be the minimal change required to achieve actual behaviour closer to what (I believe) was you original intention.

Additionally, I would recommend refactoring so that `recommendation incur cost` becomes part of the LHS, not an if in a RHS which is often considered a "code smell" for rules.

You might find some other helpful considerations in the small leaflet here: https://blog.kie.org/2013/02/design-patterns-in-production-systems-wolfgang-laun.html